# Using facebook chat with out the web interface or Pidgin?

Tags: facebook, instant-messaging

Is there a way to use facebook chat with out facebook's web interface or Pidgin? I'm not a pidgin user so the Pidgin plugin isn't an option.

Comment: What's the problem with Pidgin? You don't have to use Pidgin for all of your accounts, you could just use it for Facebook.

Comment: You have a number of answers so far that look good to me; if you want more specific responses, though, you might follow up by saying why you want to avoid Pidgin.

Comment: I'm a screen reader user and pidgin doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 2):

Kopete has a plugin. http://duncan.mac-vicar.com/blog/archives/557 it works so-so

Answer (score 2):

[Meebo](http://www.meebo.com/) can access Facebook. You can use it's "pop out" feature if you want each chat to have it's own window like a normal IM client. I don't see what's wrong with just using Pidgin though.

Comment: I'm a screen reader user and pidgin doesn't work with my screen reader. I'm also not a big fan of meebo since it is a web based client.

Answer (score 2):

[IMO.IM](https://imo.im/), a similar service to Meebo mentioned by Brendan, also has face book and a pseudo-stand alone client for windows desktops that runs in a stripped down IE.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com/) as a Facebook chat client (and Live, Gtalk and IRC, but that's not the point). 
Works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm a screen reader user the only multi protocol IM client that works for me is [Miranda](http://www.miranda-im.org) I just recently found a facebook plugin, it can be found along with other bleeding edge plugins at
http://dev.miranda.im/~jarvis/